# Why do bacteriophages look like tiny little robots?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, microscopy, bacteriophage

I get it, evolution is funny and works in mysterious ways. But come on. You can't tell me [this thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteriophage#/media/File:PhageExterior.svg) doesn't look like a nanobot.

Why do bacteriophages look this way? With their cylindrical heads and multiple "feet"?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Personally I think the question is reversed; the discovery bacteriophages pre-dated the design of nanobots; hence the question ought to be "why do nanobots look like bacteriophages?" and as such it's not really a biology question.  For it to be a good fit for the site, you'll have to show clear biological links rather than visual links with modern technology.

Comment: Why do they look like that? Because they do - there's not some deeper reason why they might look similar other than because people might have designed nanobots to look like bacteriophages (or maybe they didn't), especially given 'nanobot' doesn't have a strictly defined shape.

Comment: Honestly, that only looks like a functional bacteriophage to me, so, yes, I can tell you that doesn't look like a nanobot to me. Then again, I studied bacteriophages, but never nanobots. I wouldn't recognize a nanobot if I was shown a photograph of one.

Answer (score 3):

Many things on nanoscale look like small crystals or several small crystals put together - i.e., they adopt a limited number of symmetric shapes allowed for packing identical objects in three dimensions (see, e.g., [the shapes given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geodesic_polyhedra_and_Goldberg_polyhedra)). [Viral capsids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsid), composed of many identical proteins (capsomers) is an example of such crystal structures.

Answer (score 3):

The reason they look like that is because they have very small genomes so they have to build themselves out of multiple copies of a few building blocks. This leads to a high degree of symmetry in the component pieces; in particular icosahedral symmetry in the genome storage capsid (made of 235 copies in the smallest phage, 3115 copies in G-phage, as described by [Caspar Klug theory](https://viralzone.expasy.org/8577)) and helical symmetry in the tail. (made of an arbitrary number of copies, depending on the length.)

Industrial manufacturing also relies on efficient use of standardized mass-produced parts, so it's not surprising that you'd see similarities.

Also due to various differences between bacterial and eukaryotic cells, bacteriophage rely on their own complex protein machinery to physically breach their hosts, rather than tricking the host into using its own membrane machinery to import the virus.